# Database access in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, orm, zend-framework2

I want to find a good way to go about accessing my database from ZF2. I don't want to do this from my models or controllers and I don't want to use any ORM tools such as Doctrine (unless someone does a good job of convincing me!).

The [tutorial application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#the-model-files) is using the Table Data Gateway pattern; it creates a class `AlbumTable` which accesses the `album` table in the database. I am concerned about this approach because I will be making a normalized database where I need to join several tables to represent some models. As far as I understand, this cannot be done with the `TableGateway` class. Sure, you could do `$tblgateway->getSql()` and go from there, but that kind of defeats the purpose of the Table Data Gateway pattern I think.

So, I turned my attention to `Zend\Db\Sql\Sql`. Building on the Album example, I got the following working:

```
class AlbumMapper {
    private $sql;

    public function __construct(Sql $sql) {
        $this->sql = $sql;
    }

    public function getAlbum($id) {
        $id = (int) $id;

        $select = $this->sql->select();
        $select->from('album');
        $select->where(array('id' => $id));

        $statement = $this->sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject($select);
        $result = $statement->execute();
        $row = $result->current();

        $album = null;

        if ($row) {
            $album = new Album();

            $album->setTitle($row['title']);
            $album->setArtist($row['artist']);
            $album->setId($row['id']);
        }

        return $album;
    }
}
```

The point here is that I could call `$select->join()` and join several tables, which would give me more control of querying my database and remove the 1:1 relationship between my models and the tables. However, if I do not need to join, then using the Table Data Gateway would surely save me from writing a bunch of code.

So, I guess my question is if a combination of the two approaches would be good depending on the situation? For instance, if I only need to access a single table (no joining with others), then I could use the Table Data Gateway, and if I need to join several tables, I could go with the other approach. Is this a good or bad idea? Are there any better alternatives?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Mapper classes with Entity objects. To avoid writing too much repetitive code for the simple use-cases, I use ZfcBase's [AbstractDbMapper](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcBase/blob/master/src/ZfcBase/Mapper/AbstractDbMapper.php) to extends my specific mappers from.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I slightly modified the `AbstractDbMapper` class and did a [sample implementation](http://pastebin.com/dqPfnsGA). It works fine, but I would appreciate if you would take a short moment to see if that is what you meant (and if you have any improvements). Thanks.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I would consider instantiating the hydrator directly in UserMapper as it's tied to the User entity object's implementation and isn't something that you can easily swap without changing the implementation of User too.